# How to redeploy an Angular 2+ project to firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a small Angular 2+ project which I deployed to filebase and I needed to make some changes and redeploy.

I searched to see how to redeploy but found no answers so I just ran firebase deploy again. It said it worked but according to the firebase console only 1 file was uploaded and my site only displayed the firebase welcome message.

I have rolled back the change and followed some advice that said to do a hard refresh of cache, which I did but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I continued to research this problem and found this in the firebase documentation. The only problem I did not know what question to ask.

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/updating-a-deployment

I hope this will help someone else.